# The text printed by the PIL library does not have the best definition

Tags: java, python, image

I created a Python code that prints a text on an image using PIL library, the code makes it perfectly, but there is one problem ...
I use white image in PNG format and blue text, the text is an email, the code prints the mail perfectly in the picture, but it is not quite right that text, ie not seen the letters perfectly as It would for example if you write to the Windows Paint, being that Paint is the most basic, yet the text printed PIL is not exactly equal to that prints the Windows Paint, Paint windows is of better quality, if We see this picture:

http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/texto-1414832.png

we see that the above text is written with PIL, while the text below is written with Paint and while very little noticeable difference, I would like to make it exactly like Windows Paint, and the truth is not the same .. . I used to be different and the same source code and no case! until I use the quality property with a value of 100 and yet the text above it shows you do not have as much quality as the text below, if you look carefully, you will see that it is as I say, the quality is not the same, the quality of PIL text used to print text that is of lower quality than the paint.

What's more ... it seems that used to be another source ... which is exactly the same, the truth is I do not like and I wonder if there is any way that the text prints have better quality or PIL is best defined as The Paint.

This is the code that I have currently:

```
imagen = Image.open("img.png")
img = imagen.resize((175, 60))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Verdana.ttf", 15)
draw.text((10, 4),"mimail@hotmail.com",(0,79,255),font=font)
img.save('texto.png', format='PNG', subsampling=0, quality=100)
```

Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to render your image at a multiple of the size you require, then `resize` it with `filter=Image.ANTIALIAS`.

Here is an example using a resize factor of 2:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

imageSize = (400,100) # 2x size of the image you originally wanted.

img = Image.new("RGB", imageSize, "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Verdana.ttf", 15 * 2) # 2x of the font you wanted.
draw.text((10, 4),"mimail@hotmail.com",(0,79,255), font=font)

# downsample with Antialias by 2
img.thumbnail( (imageSize[0]/2, imageSize[1]/2), Image.ANTIALIAS) 

img.save('texto.png')
```

Comment: Hello :-) thank you very much for your help, it has worked very well your code, brother thanks for this great hand you gave me.
 I send you a hug and thanks again :-)

Comment: thank you very much for the welcome, very kind of you :-)